# How to set width of dynamically created th using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating dynamic headers of a table like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" class="shrink">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectedAll" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="selectAll()" />
        </th>
        <th class="header" data-href="" rel="tooltip" title="" ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders" width="header.width">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="Search(1,header.colName,
                    sorting.reverseSort=!sorting.reverseSort)">
                        {{header.name}}
                        <span ng-show="orderBy == header.colName">
                            <i ng-class="sorting.reverseSort ? 'fa fa-sort-asc' : 'fa fa-sort-desc'"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>

        </th>
        <th width="10%" class="last shrink"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

But “header.width” is not applying as it is in a same element as ng-repeat.

So what is work around for this?

Please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use curly braces:

```
<th class="header" data-href="" rel="tooltip" title="" ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders" width="{{header.width}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <th title="" ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders" ng-style="{'width': header.width}">
```